# Apache Beam - combine input with DoFn output

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have a `DoFn` class with `process` method, which takes a string and enhance it:

```
class LolString(apache_beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element: str) -> str:
         return element + "_lol"
```

I want to have a step in my Beam pipeline that gives me a tuple, for example:

`"Stack" -> ("Stack", "Stack_lol")`

This is my pipeline step (`strings` is a `PCollection[str]`):

```
strings | "Lol string" >> apache_beam.ParDo(LolString())
```

However this gives me the output, as per example:

`"Stack_lol"`

but I want the mentioned tuple.

How can I achieve desired output WITHOUT modifying the `process` method?

Comment: Can you explain more why you don't want to modify the `process` method? Are you reusing a library such that you can't modify the code? I don't think there's any affordance in the Beam model to retain an input and pair that up with output of a transform; that DoFn would need to specifically output the unmodified and modified pair.

Comment: yeah, it's a lib and it's used in few other places in the project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1 : if you can change the `DoFn`**

Returns the `Tuple` in the `DoFn`

```py
def test_dofn_tuple(self):
    
    class LolString(apache_beam.DoFn):
        def process(self, element: str) -> Tuple[str, str]:
            return element, f"{element}_lol"

    with TestPipeline() as p:
        (
                p
                | beam.Create(['Stack'])
                | 'Add Tuple' >> ParDo(LolString())
                | 'Log Result' >> beam.Map(print)
        )
```

- I put the code snippet in a unit test.
- The `DoFn` class take the given `str` element and returns a `Tuple[str, str]` : `(element, element_lol)`.
- I print the result in my test.

**Solution 2 : if you can't change the `DoFn`**

```py
def test_dofn_tuple(self):
    
    class LolString(DoFn):
        def process(self, element: str):
            yield element + "_lol"

    class LolStringTuple(DoFn):
        def process(self, element: str) -> Tuple:
            yield tuple(element.split('_'))

    with TestPipeline() as p:
        (
                p
                | 'Create' >> beam.Create(['Stack'])
                | 'Add Suffix' >> ParDo(LolString())
                | 'Create Tuple' >> ParDo(LolStringTuple())
                | 'Log Result' >> beam.Map(print)
        )
```

In the second solution, a new `DoFn` was added in addition of the other.
This `DoFn` splits the `str` and create the expected `Tuple`

**The same solution but with a `Map` instead of `DoFn` for the creation of the `Tuple` :**

```py
def test_dofn_tuple(self):
    
    class LolString(DoFn):
        def process(self, element: str):
            yield element + "_lol"

    with TestPipeline() as p:
        (
                p
                | 'Create' >> beam.Create(['Stack'])
                | 'Add Suffix' >> ParDo(LolString())
                | 'Create Tuple' >> beam.Map(lambda e: tuple(e.split('_')))
                | 'Log Result' >> beam.Map(print)
        )
```